# Possible to format a float in non-scientific format?

Tags: .net, string-formatting

I'm trying to convert a float to a string without getting scientific (1.13E-8) style formatting.

I'm looking for some combination of the "F" and "R" specifiers. I want the F so that it does not use the scientific style, but I also want the R so that it uses as little space as necessary to exactly represent the number.

So given 0.000000001, the string version should be 0.000000001. Not 1E-09, and not 0.000000001000.

Is it possible to tell the system "make it fixed point, but use the minimum digits necessary to exactly specify the number"?

If not, what would a good workaround be? I was thinking: use a precision of 20 and then just hack off trailing 0's if there's a '.' in the string. Anything better?

Edit:

Here's the version I have been using. I was really hoping there would be a format specifier I could use to make it do this instead.

```
var s = f.ToString("F20");
if (s.Contains("."))
{
    s = s.TrimEnd('0').TrimEnd('.');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will display only the significant digits after the decimal point, up to 10 d.

```
var format = "#0.##########";

string.Format(1.23, format);
// 1.23

string.Format(1.23456, format);
// 1.23456

string.Format(1.230045, format);
// 1.230045

string.Format(1.2345678912345, format);
// 1.2345678912
```

The key here is that the `#` signifier only outputs a digit if it is *significant*.

Hopefully that goes some way towards what you want, at least. If not, you can always write a custom `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that "exactly specify the number" might not be possible. The number might involve repetition in base 2. Think about how 1/3 repeats in base 10 as `0.33333333...`. This happens in base 2 as well, only worse. However, you can use "r" to get a value that will roundtrip.

Using `"F20"` and then trimming *will not* produce the same result as shifting the decimal place in the `"r"` format. On `Math.PI`, your code produces `3.14159265358979`. The roundtrip should be `3.1415926535897931`.

For example, here is how you might shift the decimal point on the `"r"` format.

```
static string FormatMinDigits(double d)
{
    String r = d.ToString("r", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    if (Double.IsInfinity(d) || Double.IsNaN(d))
        return r;
    String us = r.TrimStart('-');
    int epos = us.IndexOf('E');
    string mantissa;
    int exponent;
    if (epos == -1)
    {
        mantissa = us;
        exponent = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        mantissa = us.Substring(0, epos);
        exponent = Int32.Parse(us.Substring(epos + 1));
    }
    int dotPos = mantissa.IndexOf('.');
    if (dotPos == -1)
        dotPos = mantissa.Length;
    mantissa = mantissa.Replace(".", "");
    string s;
    if (exponent > 0)
    {
        if (exponent + dotPos - mantissa.Length > 0)
            mantissa += new String('0', exponent + dotPos - mantissa.Length);
        s = mantissa.Insert(exponent + dotPos, ".").TrimEnd('.');
    }
    else if (exponent < 0)
    {
        if (-(exponent + dotPos) > 0)
            mantissa = new String('0', -(exponent + dotPos)) + mantissa;
        s = mantissa.Insert(0, "0.");
    }
    else
        s = mantissa.Insert(dotPos, ".").TrimEnd('.');
    if (d < 0)
        s = '-' + s;
    if (double.Parse(s, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) != d) // Since format "r", it should roundtrip.
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Internal error in FormatMinDigits: {0:r}", r));
    return s;
}
```